# AngularJS: Multiplying Two Numbers within an Object and then Obtaining the Total

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small issue regarding how to multiply numbers within an object in AngularJS. What I would like to do is change the following code from multiplying two numbers inside the HTML using AngularJS into a service or factory. Here is the working HTML (input is `md-text-float` from Angular Material), controller and factory in AngularJS:

HTML:

```
 <md-text-float ng-repeat="macro in macros"
                    md-theme="deep-orange"
                    label="{{macro.type}}"
                    type="number"
                    ng-model="macro.amount">
  </md-text-float>

<div class="tCalories md-whiteframe-z1" ng-repeat="macro in macros">
       <span class="subtitles">{{macro.type}}</span>
        <div class="macros">{{ macro.amount * macro.multiplier }}</div>
        <md-tooltip>{{macro.tip}}</md-tooltip>
</div>
<div class="tCalories md-whiteframe-z1">
        <span class="subtitles">Total Calories</span>
        <div class="macros total">{{totals() | number: 2}}</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('dataAdd', ['$scope', 'MacroCalculation', function($scope, MacroCalculation) {

$scope.macros = MacroCalculation.macros();
$scope.totals = MacroCalculation.totals();

}]);
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('MacroCalculation', function() {

var macros = [
   {'type': 'Protein', 'amount': null,'multiplier': 4,'tip': 'Calories per gram of protein'},
   {'type': 'Carbohydrate', 'amount': null, 'multiplier': 4, 'tip': 'Calories per gram of carbohydrate'},
   {'type': 'Fat', 'amount': null, 'multiplier': 9, 'tip': 'Calories per gram of fat'}
 ];


var getMacros = function() {
    return macros;
};


var totals = function() {
    for (var i = 0, values = 0, length = macros.length; i < length; i++) {
        values += macros[i].amount * macros[i].multiplier;
    }
       return values;
};


var getTotals = function() {
  return totals;
};

return {
    macros: getMacros,
    totals: getTotals

}

});
```

I get the totals fine using `{{totals()}}`; however, I would like to move `{{macro.amount * macro.multiplier}}` into a function inside a factory as well. I am not sure how to loop through `macros` in the factory in order to do the same calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should help you.

```
var macros = [
    {
        'type': 'Protein',
        'amount': null,
        'multiplier': 4,
        'tip': 'Calories per gram of protein',
        'total': function() { return this.amount * this.multiplier; }
    }
];
```

You can do the same for everyone.
And if you wanna a single function, to handle this.

```
var singleTotal = function(macro) {
    return macro.amount * macro.multiplier;
}
```

I think this should solve your problem.

And AngularJS have his own [forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function.
Try to implement:

```
var totals = function() {
    var values = 0; // declarate all vars, it's a good pratice
    angular.forEach(macros, function(macro, index) {
        values += macro.amount * macro.multiplier;
    });
    return values;
};
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me in the end. Basically, I used the top portion of the answer to write a function "total" in the object. Once I did that, everything started to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your service code (Copy & Paste):

```
    app.factory('MacroCalculation', function() {

     ....

    function calculate(index) {
        //do your math here
    } 
    return {
        macros: getMacros,
        totals: getTotals,
        calculate: calculate 
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** Add this function also to your controller.

```
<div class="tCalories md-whiteframe-z1" ng-repeat="macro in macros"> 
    <span class="subtitles">{{macro.type}}</span> 
    <div class="macros">{{ calculate($index) }}</div> 
    <md-tooltip>{{macro.tip}}</md-tooltip> 
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I didn't add the controller in my code because the controller I am using works fine. Thanks for the response, but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: You can create a function which receives the index of the macro and multiplies. You can provide the index like so from your html: {{calculate($index)}}